# Facebook JSDK alert on login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been reading several answers on this topic but I couldn't make it work. This is what I am trying:

```
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '247886858583094',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
       FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(response) { alert('You logged in'); } );
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
```

What do I add to get an alert on user login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(response) {
        alert('You logged in');
    }
);`

Add this code inside the scope of `window.fbAsyncInit = function()`

Comment: I added that line just below the code. But it doesn't display the alert. http://lujanventas.com/entrar/index2.php

Comment: Place it inside the scope of window.fbAsyncInit = function()

Comment: I just changed the code and it's still not working. (I edited the question to match it)

Comment: I'm getting an error message in the console "unsafe javascript access". Though it seems to have to do with the FB popup but that's working normally

Comment: Seems I wasn't loggin in due to a Chrome specific bug. The alert works fine in other browsers.